# How can I count list elements in unordered list? (RSpec/Capybara)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

In my site I have this list:

```
<ul class="test">
  <li class="social_1"></li>
  <li class="social_2"></li>
  <li class="social_3"></li>
  <li class="social_3"></li>
</ul>
```

My question is: how can I count **li** in my **ul** class test
I have tried this:

```
my_ul = page.find("ul[class='test']")
my_ul.each do |li|
  pp li['class']
end
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there anyway to do something like I coded above?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245702/watir-webdriver-counting-number-of-items-in-a-ul-list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

assuming ul parent element with id=parent .. you can do it like this

```
  list = Array.new 
  list = find('#parent ul').all('li')
```

now you can get list size simply

```
list.size
```

and you can benefit from having all li's in array to collect text also in each li like this

```
  list = find('#parent ul').all('li').collect(&:text)
```

Answer (score 11):

I'd advise using the new RSpec 3 syntax for counting elements with Capybara:

```
it "should have 4 li elements" do
   expect(find('ul.text')).to have_selector('li', count: 4)
end
```

More information here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#querying

Comment: Thanks for your great answer @JellyFishBoy! I'm glad I scrolled down. The new rspec 3 syntax will wait until the condition is met, or up to the rspec timeout. So it will allow for some time for the condition to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Use `page.all("ul.test li").size`